# Windows 2008 R2: Redirection permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, folder-redirection

I am having a problem with the permissions for folder redirection.  As a result, I did some research and changed my permissions.  The NTFS and Share permissions have been configured according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274443 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288991.

When I create a new profile on the server, the permissions are correct.  When I log in as a regular user I do not have permission to the documents folder and the AppData folder.  I have not checked other folders.

So.. I compared the permissions from the original folders and the newly created profile folder.  They are the same.  I rebooted the server (shouldn't matter -- but just in case)..

Even though the NTFS and Share permissions are showing the same on the folder that works and the folder that does not work, the original folders do not work (they do not allow users to view or create files or folders).

I am at a loss now....  Any ideas?

Comment: well since your an iphone guy I'm sure your lost!

Comment: just had to do that, anyway when you say "create a new profile" are you saying that you manually create the directory or just editing the profile settings within AD and then just letting the user login to build the actual directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use on user active directory side Home drive, for example Z: , to map to \server\home\%username%
(use % sign to automate username :) )
also , in group policy, choose option on my documents to redirect to users home drive.

This will make when you create AD user to create folder with correct NTFS permissions.